# Execution of .run file

Tags: installation

Trying to install a display driver .run file in the terminal using Ubuntu 18.04. I was told that using ./FILENAME.run should to the trick. What's the problem?

```
bruno@bruno:~/Downloads/displaylink$ ls -l
total 23904
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno 12332791 Feb  4 10:57  displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run
-r-------- 1 bruno bruno 12102697 Mai 17 10:14 'DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 5.1.zip'
-rw-r--r-- 1 bruno bruno    40054 Feb 13 13:35  LICENSE


bruno@bruno:~/Downloads/displaylink$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run
sudo: ./displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run: command not found
```

Comment: Does the file have execute permission? Update your question with `ls -l` results instead of plain `ls`.

Comment: I think so since it says "Permission denied" when I don't include the "sudo". I edited the $ls$ part.

Comment: Lack of execute permission is the problem: do `chmod -v uga+x displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run`. It's a common problem with down-loaded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the `.run` file will not run is that it lacks execute permission. This is a common problem with down-loaded files, and it is easily corrected:

```
chmod -v uga+x displaylink-driver-5.1.26.run
```

Since the file is owned by `bruno` there is no need to use `sudo` to change the permissions. Setting `all execute` makes sure that the file will run under `sudo`.